# Jackson parse json with a one-to-many relationship in a single step

Tags: java, jackson

I would like to parse a JSON file that contains two array of objects and a relationship between those, this is an example:

```
{
    "a": [
        {
            "name": "one",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "two",
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "three",
            "id": 3
        }
    ],
    "b": [
        {
            "name": "cool",
            "a_id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "better",
            "a_id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "no_id",
            "a_id": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to map those to two entities, `Aentity` and `Bentity`, where `Aentity` should contain an array of `Bentities`.

And I would also like to have the list of `Bentities` with null a_id.

Is this possible to do with jackson in a single parsing? How?

Note: I'm asking because the file that I have to parse is relatively big.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you've asked for by having both an `id` and `a_id` property on your `Bentity` as follows:

```
public class JacksonParsing {

    private static final String JSON = "{\n" +
            "    \"a\": [\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"name\": \"one\",\n" +
            "            \"id\": 1\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"name\": \"two\",\n" +
            "            \"id\": 2\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"name\": \"three\",\n" +
            "            \"id\": 3\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    ],\n" +
            "    \"b\": [\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"name\": \"cool\",\n" +
            "            \"a_id\": 1\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"name\": \"better\",\n" +
            "            \"a_id\": 1\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"name\": \"no_id\",\n" +
            "            \"a_id\": null\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "}";

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Aentity result = objectMapper.readValue(JSON, Aentity.class);

        System.out.println(result.getB().get(0).getName());
    }

    static class Aentity {

        private List<Bentity> a;
        private List<Bentity> b;

        public Aentity() {

        }

        public List<Bentity> getA() {
            return a;
        }

        public void setA(List<Bentity> a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public List<Bentity> getB() {
            return b;
        }

        public void setB(List<Bentity> b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

    }

    static class Bentity {

        private String name;
        private Integer id;
        private Integer a_id;

        public Bentity() {

        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Integer getA_id() {
            return a_id;
        }

        public void setA_id(Integer a_id) {
            this.a_id = a_id;
        }
    }

}
```

However you may be better off where `Aentity` has a `name` and `id` property, while `Bentity` has a `name` and `a_id` property (i.e. different types) both contained by a different parent object.